# how to stop command prompt from closing in c# after executing tf command

Tags: c#, cmd, source-control-explorer

I create a file by `ResXResourceWriter` and generate. when I want to add it source control by

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\Common7\\IDE\\TF.exe", " add " + myFile);
```

a command prompt window will open a red line shown and quickly closed. So I can't read the error. What should I do to prevent the window from closing?

Comment: Is there any reason a classic `Console.ReadLine()` doesn't work?

Comment: I try it before and it doesn't work

Comment: Define "It doesn't work." Actually, come to think of it, grab the `Process` that results from the `Start` command, and call [`WaitForExit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb4aw7b8(v=vs.110).aspx) on what results from that. It sounds like that'll work for what you're doing.

Comment: Of course Console.ReadLine() doesn't work since it's an external application and not the current one that is closing. Reading for input in this application has no effect on another.

Comment: One way is to call [AllocConsole()](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/AllocConsole.html) first.  The program now will use your console window, it won't close until you call FreeConsole().

Answer (score 1):

Redirect standard output (or standard error) of the command and then call Console.WriteLine() in your program to show it.  See example here:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Run the command via cmd.exe and give it the /k flag. This way the window will stay open.

Comment: Yes, so you tell your code to run cmd /k tf instead of just tf and it will stay open.